# have a relative shebang line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scripting, cron, shebang

I'm writing a rails app and need to run come scripts through `./script/runner`

while i could put

```
#!/home/cannon/src/timetracker/script/runner
```

at the top, that wont work in production where it needs to be more like

```
#!/var/www/loclahost/htdocs/timetracker/script/runner -e=production
```

since `./script` is not in my path, and I don't want it to be, how can I allow this to be set up,

I am using a cron job to run it on a Linux box

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`env`](http://man.cx/env) in the shebang line to look things up in the path:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ./script/runner
```

Comment: This is how all shebangs should be written, as it means your script doesn't require a program to be installed in a certain location. eg `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: so i can pass a relative path to env? will that be relative to the script's location, or from where it is called, which idk where cron's pwd is...

Comment: Oh, it's relative to your cwd. Cron's man page should be able to tell you.

Comment: this is WORTHLESS, since as mentioned by Josh, it's relative to the _caller's_ current path, not the path of the script file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this at the top of your (ruby) script to re-exec it under the local ./script/runner (which should then define Rails so you avoid an infinite loop)

```
exec("./script/runner",$0,*ARGV) unless defined?(Rails)
```

(So use a regular 'ruby' shebang at the top, whether it's `#!/usr/bin/ruby` or `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` or whatever the flavor)

Comment: Requires the installing user to have ruby already in their path.

Comment: Well - not in their path, but they need to know the path to ruby to put it in the shebang line.

Answer (score 0):

Now that script/runner is gone and Rails 7 uses "rails runner", there are problems using that in a shebang line with env because env doesn't parse spaces and looks for 'rails runner'.

This is the most elegant solution I found:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

if not defined?(Rails) then
  exec('bin/rails', 'runner', __FILE__, *ARGV)
end

... Rails code ...
```

It's from https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/665.